# Using junctions in PATH

Tags: windows, path, dll, junction

I've noticed a couple of times that it looks like I can't use NTFS junctions under %SystemRoot%, put the ensuing file path in my PATH, and get it to work for DLL lookup.

For example, if I put a vendor's "bin" directory under there as a junction, and put it in my %PATH%, then I can run executables there just by typing the executable's name on the command line (without the path), but they immediately throw up a dialog that the DLLs the executable uses from that same directory cannot be found.

If I instead put the vendor's "bin" directory path directly into the %PATH%, they run fine.

What exactly is going on here? Is there a good reason for it, or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You’re forgetting the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).

If the program you are running is 32-bit, then `c:\windows\system32` silently redirects to `c:\windows\SysWOW64`.

You haven’t placed the bin folder under syswow64 and so it doesn’t exist.

Not a bug at all. Just standard Windows behavior you should be aware of.

Comment: That's a very good point (so I've upvoted you). However, I did indeed do exactly that. In particular, there's a junction pointing to the same folder (which contains only 32-bit exes and DLLs) under both %SystemRoot%\system32\ and %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\. I added *both* of those folders to PATH jic. The exes can be found that way, but not the DLLs.

Comment: ...my *suspicion* is MS disabled DLL lookups through junctions (perhaps only %SystemRoot% junctions?) to forestall OS attacks, but I can't find anything saying that.